# Trying to ljust, center, and rjust output of stopwatch

Tags: python

I have a stopwatch program that is fully functional.  All I am trying to do is format the output to be aligned.

This was a section of the code before trying to edit:

```
 lapTime = round(time.time() - lastTime, 2)
 totalTime = round(time.time() - startTime, 2)
 print ('Lap #%s: %s (%s)' % (lapNum, totalTime, lapTime), end='')
```

This was one of the attempts to align the output:

```
 print ('Lap ', lapNum.ljust(10, ' ')), ':',totalTime.center(20, ' '), 
 lapTime.rjust(30, ' '))
```

I am getting the error:

```
 File "D:/stopwatch2.py", line 19, in main
     print ('Lap ' + str(lapNum.ljust(10, ' ')), ':',totalTime.center(40, 
 ' '), lapTime.rjust(50, ' '))
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ljust'
```

Comment: Error is pretty readable. And you posted a different code from what you have run.

Answer (score 2):

`ljust` and `center` are string methods. You have to convert the value to strings before you call those methods:

```
print ('Lap ', str(lapNum).ljust(10, ' '), ':', str(totalTime).center(20, ' '))
```

You can also use `str.format` and the [format options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
print ('Lap {:<10}: {:=20}'.format(lapNum, totalTime))
# output: Lap 1         :           1557332386
```

With `str.format` the conversion to a string is implicit.

Comment: Oh man thank you so much!  I tried converting it to a string but my issue was literally just a paren thanks!